# Use sqlite database in iphone using xcode 4.3.2

Tags: iphone

How to use sqlite database in iphone using xcode 4.3.2....
I am having problem in finding path of my database ?? since i had copied FormDB.sqlite in Database folder in my app....Please help me as i am new to iphone programming...

calling this method in applicationDidFinishLaunching of Appdelegate file but it is returning success=false

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

    //Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]; 

    if(!success) {

        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FormDB.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if (!success) 
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }   
}

- (NSString *) getDBPath {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FormDB.sqlite"];
}
```

Comment: Process should be the same, bundle SQLite database with app, copy database to Documents or Library directory on first launch, use database. What have you tried thats not working?

Comment: You probably forgot to copy database to Documents directory at first launch... It's usually dan in (custom) methods with names like createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded or similiar. You'll find a nice tutorial here: http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AppDelegate.h` file declare

```
@interface AppDelegate{

        NSString *databaseName;
    NSString *databasePath;

}
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase;
@end
```

and then in

```
@implementation AppDelegate{

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
        // Setup some globals
        databaseName = @"FormDB.sqlite";

        // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

        // Execute the "checkAndCreateDatabase" function
        [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

        // Query the database for all animal records and construct the "animals" array
        [self readAnimalsFromDatabase];

        // Configure and show the window
        [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    -(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
        // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
        BOOL success;

        // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
        // of the database and to copy it over if required
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
        success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

        // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
        if(success) return;

        // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

        // Get the path to the database in the application package
        NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

        // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

        [fileManager release];
    }
}
@end
```

try this code 
May this Help you....
:-)

Comment: release the filemanager if success is YES and you return.  also [...] around the call to create databasePathFromApp